# IIS | PHP Error: No input file specified

Tags: php, iis

Im running IIS 7.5 / PHP 7.0 CGI. If i open a **non exist** .php file in my browser, i get this error:

> No input file specified.

IIS don't use the 404 Error Page for .php, like in .html files. I found some solutions, for example set **doc_root** in php.ini or comment out **open_basedir** .. but it won't help. I know it's a server issue, but not which.

The question is: Why i get "No input file specified." output, if i open a non exist .php file and not the IIS 404 Error Page?

Comment: Are you asking a question? This looks like a statement.

Comment: Yes, its a question ..

Comment: Well then what's the question? You've posted a statement. Perhaps you could rewrite your statement as a question and add some relevant details.

Comment: The question is: Why i get "No input file specified." output, if i open a non exist .php file and not the IIS 404 Error Page? Btw .. i gave you all details what you need ..

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: IIS 7 > Site > Handler Mappings > Edit handler > Request Restrictions > Mapping tab > Check "Invoke Handler only if request is mapped to:" > Select "File or folder"

Comment: I have same issue and It's already *File or folder* selected but still same error.

Comment: @Riz did you ever figure it out? :(

Comment: If above mapping is correct, Please check document root path in php.ini file